Next.js, typescript and PostgreSQL filter for a GenericTable component
I am creating an application in Next.js that uses Typescript. It fetches data from a database table customers and shows it.
I have programmed the table so that it has the following functions

Search
Sort (asc-desc)
Filter by column (show what is selected in select-list)

I am unable to finish the filter by column and need some guidance.
I will start this questions with screenshots of the solution as it is, and then I will add the code. The component that shows the generic table is called app/components/GenericTable.tsx, and is called on like this:
  const operationalStatuses: string[] = Array.from(new Set(customersData?.data.map((customer: any) => customer.customer_operational_status)));
  const countryHqs: string[] = Array.from(new Set(customersData?.data.map((customer: any) => customer.customer_country_hq)));
  const customersColumns = [
    { key: 'customer_name', label: 'Name'},
    { key: 'customer_name_abbreviated', label: 'Abbr' },
    { key: 'customer_operational_status', label: 'Operational status', filterOptions: operationalStatuses },
    { key: 'customer_operational_operational_date_saying', label: 'Operational date' },
    { key: 'customer_country_hq', label: 'HQ', filterOptions: countryHqs },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Customers</h1>

        
        
      <GenericTable<CustomerI>
          data={customersData?.data || []}
          columns={customersColumns}
          searchPlaceholder="Search..."
          onRowClick={(customer) => {
            router.push(`/customers/${customer.customer_id}`);
          }}
        />
        

    </>
  );


Table:


Search (is working):


Filter shows unique data:


I have managed to show what column I want to filter by in the URL:


app/types/CustomerI.ts
// app/types/CustomerI.ts

interface CustomerI {
  customer_id: number;
  customer_name: string;
  customer_name_abbreviated: string;
  customer_country_hq: string;
  customer_operational_status: string;
  customer_operational_operational_date_saying: string;
}

app/(private)/customers/page.tsx
// app/(private)/customers/page.tsx
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Link from "next/link";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useState, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import GenericTable from "@/app/components/GenericTable";

export default function Customers() {
  const router = useRouter();
  
  // Get customers
  const { data: customersData, error: customersError, isLoading: customersIsLoading } = useSWR("/customers/api-customers/api-get-customers/");
  if (customersError) return <div className="error_smal"><span>Failed to load. Please check permissions.</span></div>;
  if (customersIsLoading) return ( <div><div className="loading"></div><span>Loading...</span></div> );


  // Define columns
  const operationalStatuses: string[] = Array.from(new Set(customersData?.data.map((customer: any) => customer.customer_operational_status)));
  const countryHqs: string[] = Array.from(new Set(customersData?.data.map((customer: any) => customer.customer_country_hq)));
  const customersColumns = [
    { key: 'customer_name', label: 'Name'},
    { key: 'customer_name_abbreviated', label: 'Abbr' },
    { key: 'customer_operational_status', label: 'Operational status', filterOptions: operationalStatuses },
    { key: 'customer_operational_operational_date_saying', label: 'Operational date' },
    { key: 'customer_country_hq', label: 'HQ', filterOptions: countryHqs },
  ];


  // Return
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Customers</h1>

        
        
      <GenericTable<CustomerI>
          data={customersData?.data || []}
          columns={customersColumns}
          searchPlaceholder="Search..."
          onRowClick={(customer) => {
            router.push(`/customers/${customer.customer_id}`);
          }}
        />
        

    </>
  );
}

customers/api-customers/api-get-customers Customer test data
{"data":[{"customer_id":32,"customer_name":"InGen Corporation","customer_name_abbreviated":"InGen","customer_country_hq":"Costa Rica","customer_operational_status":"Exercise","customer_operational_operational_date_saying":"06.15.2019"},{"customer_id":33,"customer_name":"Nordic Tech Solutions AS","customer_name_abbreviated":"NTS","customer_country_hq":"Oslo","customer_operational_status":"Operational","customer_operational_operational_date_saying":"15.06.2023"},{"customer_id":31,"customer_name":"Tyrell Corporation","customer_name_abbreviated":"Tyrell","customer_country_hq":"USA","customer_operational_status":"Exercise","customer_operational_operational_date_saying":"15.03.2022"},{"customer_id":34,"customer_name":"Viking Maritime Group AS","customer_name_abbreviated":"VMG","customer_country_hq":"Oslo","customer_operational_status":"Operational","customer_operational_operational_date_saying":"15.06.2023"}]}

app/util/fetcher.ts
// app/util/fetcher.ts

const fetcher = async(url: RequestInfo | URL) => {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    if (!res.ok){
        const msg = "fetcher.tsx::An error occured while fetching data";
        const info = await res.json();
        const status = res.status;
        const error = new Error(msg);
        console.error(info, status)
        throw error;
    }
    return res.json();
}

export default fetcher;

app/components/GenericTable.tsx
// app/components/GenericTable.tsx
// 
// Author: Ditlefsen
//
// This is a table that will show it self as a normal table on desktop, and cards on mobile.
//
// It has search, hide/show columns and sort controls.
// 
// It is inspired by this post on Behance: 
// https://www.behance.net/gallery/95240691/Responsive-Data-Table-Designs
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

// Column definition interface with filter options properties
interface Column {
  key: string;
  label: string;
  filterOptions?: string[];
}

// GenericTable props interface
interface GenericTableProps<T extends Record<string, any>> {
  data: T[];
  columns: Column[];
  searchPlaceholder?: string;
  onRowClick?: (item: T) => void;
  filters?: { [key: string]: string };
  onFilterChange?: (key: string, value: string) => void;
}

function GenericTable<T extends Record<string, any>>({
  data,
  columns,
  searchPlaceholder = 'Search...',
  onRowClick,
  filters = {},
  onFilterChange
}: GenericTableProps<T>) {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [sortKey, setSortKey] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState<'asc' | 'desc'>('asc');
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  console.log('GenericTable rendered');

  // Check if the user is on a mobile device
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 767);
    };

    handleResize(); // Initial check
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  // Sync filters from URL when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const newFilters: { [key: string]: string } = {};
    columns.forEach(column => {
      const value = params.get(column.key);
      if (value) {
        newFilters[column.key] = value;
      }
    });

    console.log('Filters from URL:', newFilters);

    // Notify parent component if necessary
    Object.entries(newFilters).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      console.log(`New filter value from URL: ${key} = ${value}`);
      onFilterChange?.(key, value);
    });
  }, [columns, onFilterChange]);

  // Filter data based on search query and filters
  const filteredData = data
    .filter(item =>
      columns.some(column =>
        item[column.key]?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    )
    .filter(item => {
      return Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
        item[key]?.toString() === value
      );
    });

  console.log('Filtered Data:', filteredData);

  // Sort data
  const sortedData = filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortKey === null) return 0;
    const aValue = a[sortKey]?.toString().toLowerCase();
    const bValue = b[sortKey]?.toString().toLowerCase();
    if (aValue < bValue) return sortOrder === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
    if (aValue > bValue) return sortOrder === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
    return 0;
  });

  const handleSort = (key: string) => {
    if (sortKey === key) {
      setSortOrder(sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    } else {
      setSortKey(key);
      setSortOrder('asc');
    }
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (key: string, value: string) => {
    console.log(`Filter change: ${key} = ${value}`);
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (value) {
      params.set(key, value);
    } else {
      params.delete(key);
    }
    const newUrl = `${window.location.pathname}?${params.toString()}`;
    console.log('New URL:', newUrl);
    router.push(newUrl);

    // Notify parent component if necessary
    onFilterChange?.(key, value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Search Input */}
      <form>
        <p>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder={searchPlaceholder}
          value={search}
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          className="generic-table-search-input"
        />
        </p>
      </form>

      {/* Sort Controls (Mobile) */}
      {isMobile && (
        <div className="sort-controls-mobile">
          {columns.map(column => (
            <button
              key={column.key}
              onClick={() => handleSort(column.key)}
              className={`sort-button ${sortKey === column.key ? `sorted-${sortOrder}` : ''}`}
            >
              {column.label} {sortKey === column.key && (sortOrder === 'asc' ? '▲' : '▼')}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}

      {/* Table */}
        <table className="generic-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              
              {/* Table head columns - Onlick sort */}
              {columns.map(column => (
                <th
                  key={column.key}
                  onClick={() => handleSort(column.key)}
                  className={`sortable ${sortKey === column.key ? `sorted-${sortOrder}` : ''}`}
                >
                  <span>{column.label}</span>
                  {sortKey === column.key && (
                    <span className={`sort-icon ${sortOrder}`}>
                      {sortOrder === 'asc' ? '▲' : '▼'}
                    </span>
                  )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
            <tr>
              {/* Table head filters - Onselect only show rows with that value */}
              {columns.map(column => (
                <th key={column.key}>
                  {column.filterOptions && (
                    <select
                      value={filters[column.key] || ''}
                      onChange={(e) => handleFilterChange(column.key, e.target.value)}
                      className="filter-select"
                    >
                      <option value="">All</option>
                      {column.filterOptions.map(option => (
                        <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>
                      ))}
                    </select>
                  )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {/* Table data */}
            {sortedData.map((item, index) => (
              <tr
                key={index}
                onClick={() => onRowClick?.(item)}
                className="table-row"
              >
                {columns.map(column => (
                  <td
                    key={column.key}
                    data-label={column.label}
                  >
                    {item[column.key]?.toString()}
                  </td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </>
  );
}

export default GenericTable;

CSS:
/* CSS Tables Generic Table ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* CSS Search Input for Generic Table */
input.generic-table-search-input{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* CSS Tables Generic Table */
table.generic-table {
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

table.generic-table > thead > tr > th {
  background: #36304a;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.generic-table > thead > tr > th.th-sub-headline {
  background: #fefefefe;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: left;
}
.sort-icon {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #666;
}

.sortable.sorted-asc .sort-icon {
  content: '▲';
}

.sortable.sorted-desc .sort-icon {
  content: '▼';
}
table.generic-table > thead > tr > th > span {
  color: white;
}

table.generic-table > tbody > tr {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: #cccccc 1px solid;
}

table.generic-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

table.generic-table > tbody > tr:hover {
  background: #faf4f2;
}

table.generic-table > tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 8px 6px;
  color: black;
}

table.generic-table > tbody > tr > td.important {
  background: #fff7e5;
  border-bottom: #eabc63 1px solid;
  color: black;
}

table.generic-table > tbody > tr > td.danger {
  background: #ffe7e5;
  border-bottom: #ff4940 1px solid;
  border-top: #ff4940 1px solid;
  color: black;
}

/* Responsive Styles */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  table.generic-table {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  table.generic-table th,
  table.generic-table td {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  table.generic-table thead {
    display: none;
  }

  table.generic-table tr {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  table.generic-table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
  }

  table.generic-table td::before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 45%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

